# Extending ListPointPlot3D with a 3rd variable?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to extend a function like this: (a 4x4 square)

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{x, y, 0}, {x, 0, 4, 1}, {y, 0, 4, 1}]]
```

into something like this: (a 4x4x4 cube)

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, 0, 4, 1}, {y, 0, 4, 1}, {z, 0, 4, 1}]]
```

by adding a 3rd dimension.

However, the dimensions of the latter seem to be incorrect. It seems to form a 2x2 matrix of 3d points rather than a list.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you look a bit more closely you'll see that the expression

```
Table[{x, y, z}, {x, 0, 4, 1}, {y, 0, 4, 1}, {z, 0, 4, 1}]
```

returns a structure with `5x5x5` triplets.  That is exactly what the expression is supposed to return.  You can see this if you apply the `Dimensions[]` function to the returned structure.

There are several ways to turn the table into a list of 125 triplets, one is to use `Flatten` like this

```
Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, 0, 4, 1}, {y, 0, 4, 1}, {z, 0, 4, 1}], 2]
```

Or you could simply generate your list of triplets directly; for your example one alternative would be

```
Tuples[Range[0, 4], 3]
```